# Nested menu items overlap each other

Tags: jquery, nested, dropdown

I have a nested drop-down menu. But the items overlap each other when clicked sequentially.

Code pen here:
https://codepen.io/logan-lee/pen/BaadBxg

I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        $('.dropdown-submenu ul').hide();     // this is a fix that doesn't work
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();                
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work on nested items.

If I remove the 'fix' line, the nested items overlap each other(which is the original problem).

Thanks.

Comment: It works as expected to me. What are you trying to accomplish? Why is the "fix" line a problem?

Comment: Try clicking: RPM-based->Fedora-based->Yellow Dog Linux. With the 'fix' it never gets to 'Yellow Dog Linux'.

Comment: Oh i see. You are hiding all the <ul>s with that fix. Try this `$(this).siblings('ul').hide();` instead

Comment: Now the nested items don't toggle. They are not hidden when clicked.

Comment: You are right, sorry. `$('.dropdown-submenu ul').not(this.closest('ul')).hide();`
This should work in your case.

Comment: Do you know how to vertically align nested menu? For example, click on 'Others' and 'Slackware' appears right next to 'Others'.

Comment: I do. Currently, your first list is all in one <li>. You should separate each <a> (paired with its own <ul>) into their own <li>s. Then you put `position: relative;` on <li> and `position: absolute;` on <a>s and work a bit with _top_ property maybe.

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to work.

Comment: I don't understand why this one works: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am putting all this here to be easier to read. Answers both of your question :)

HTML(Notice I separated the first list so it has 3 li-s instead of just 1):

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">           
            <div class = "navbar-header navbar-right">
                <a class = "navbar-brand" href = "#">My LINUX distros</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        My favorite Linux distros...
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">RPM-based <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Mandrake Linux</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fedora-based <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Yellow Dog Linux</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Debian-based <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Ubuntu</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Ubuntu flavors <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Lubuntu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Xubuntu</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Kubuntu</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Others <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Slackware</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>          
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</body>
```

CSS(position: absolute is neccessary on the child element):

```
.dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
            $('.dropdown-submenu ul').not(this.closest('ul')).hide();
            $(this).next('ul').toggle();                
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeh it seems to work. What did you change? HTML seems the same to mine.

Comment: your parent ul.dropdown-menu had only 1 li.dropdown-submenu (<ul><li><a></a><ul></ul><a></a><ul></ul><a></a><ul></ul></li></ul>). I just separated them in 3 li.dropdown-submenu (<ul><li><a></a><ul></ul></li><li><a></a><ul></ul></li><li><a></a><ul></ul></li></ul>).